# wget blocking subdirectiories

Tags: linux, website, wget, recursive

I would like to recursively download a page, but block link like this containing "strony":

```
http://domain.com/rozrywka/strony/2/
```

my command is

```
wget -r -nd --delete-after -e robots=off -X strony http://domain.com
```

but it's still downloading them.

Comment: is this a (possible) duplicate of this ?


  [1]: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/61642/39890

Comment: No, --exclude-directories=/strony/ does not work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found it ;)

It should be

```
-X */strony/*
```

and it works !